# Cell array index from guide

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am creating a gui that will graph an array depending on a popup menu. Let's say the choices are 'All' 'A' 'B' and 'C'. Its easy to index the cell array with the individual callback values from the popup menus. I.E.
In popup callback: val = get(hObject,'Value') -1 --> handles.val=val
In button callback: plot(cellarray(handles.val))

My question is how to do the 'All' part. Where I would typically use cellarray(:), I can't do handles.val=':' and pass it in. How can I dynamically access the whole cell array? (Let's say the cell array is a 1 x 5.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to work around the problem.

Basically I put the 'All' option at the end of the strings in the popup menu, and if the user selects it, then val is equal to 6, i.e. the number of elements in `handles.Data+1`, which makes the condition for entering an if statement.

```
function GUI_PopUp
clc
clear

%// Generate dummy data
handles.Data = cell(1,5);

x = 1:20;
handles.Data{1} = rand(1,20);
handles.Data{2} = 2.*x-5;
handles.Data{3} = x-10;
handles.Data{4} = x;
handles.Data{5} = 3.*x;

handles.x = x; % I was lazy sorry :)

%// Create GUI components
hFigure = figure('Position',[100 100 500 500],'Units','Pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[60,90,400,300]);

PopupString = {'1';'2';'3';'4';'5';'All'};
handles.Pop = uicontrol('Style','popup','Position',[100 380 40 60],'String',PopupString,'Callback',@(s,e) PopupCallback);
handles.text = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[100 460 40 30],'String','Select data');


guidata(hFigure,handles);

    function PopupCallback
       
        handles = guidata(hFigure);
        
        val = get(handles.Pop,'Value');
        
        %// If selected 'All'
        if val == (numel(handles.Data)+1)
            
            hold all
            for k = 1:numel(handles.Data)
            plot(handles.x,handles.Data{k},'parent',handles.axes1)
            end
            
        else
            
        plot(handles.x,handles.Data{val},'parent',handles.axes1)
        
        end
    end
end
```

Sample screenshot with the 'All' option selected:

[image]

Hope that helps get you started! If not please tell me I'll modify the code!